# Simple way to configure GCP custom domain for regional (Standard tier) load balancer instead of global (Premium)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

After migrating from a basic AppEngine website to serving it from Cloud Run, I've gone from paying $0.01 per month to $0.60 per **day**. That seems to be because I've switched from [regional App Engine frontend](https://cloud.google.com/skus?currency=USD&filter=E2EB-F679-D108) to [Global Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/skus?currency=USD&filter=DEE3-C42E-3E4D) (prices in those links) when I used the ["Manage Custom Domains" integration](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#run) in the Cloud Run panel to serve my basic personal web app at a custom domain.

It was easy to set up that way using that integration to create certs / DNS records / load balancer / etc, but it seems like I'm overpaying for serving improvements that are way overkill for my usage with this load balancer setup vs. the basic regional serving I got through AppEngine. So can someone help me understand the simplest/cheapest way to serve my Cloud Run service via HTTP(S) at my given domain, maybe manually editing the load balancer etc provided by this integration, or if I must deleting the whole integration and setting up the equivalent by hand?

Comment: Configuring load balancers is documented. Edit your post and provide details you are having configuring the load balancer. There are several different types. Review the docs and pricing to select the one you want. Note: Cloud Run does not require a load balancer. Also include details on why you are configuring one.

Comment: Tip: you mention pricing but provide no details on what you are being charged for. Review the docs so that you understand feature sets and the cost.

Comment: I linked directly to the relevant pricing pages, not following what you mean "no details on what you are being charged for". And it sounds like you're confused that what I'm serving from Cloud Run is the same basic web app I migrated from GAE? Tried to rewrite the question to make that clearer.